# pandas selecting rows whose sum equals to a value in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, sorting

Hi Guys i have a dataFrame where i want to  frist group rows by a column, then i find any rows that sum up to a given value in another column.

```
**A**        **B**             **c**


XCD            1                5
FFF           12                2
VB             3                6
XCD            8                5
AAA            2                7
AAA            5                7
XCD            4                5
VB             6                6
VB             3                6
FFF            2                2
```

For each unique entry in column A say XCD, the value of column C is always the same to represent the total sum needed per unique entry. To illustrate what i need, see the below final data Frame.

```
**A**        **B**             **c**


XCD            1                5
XCD            4                5
FFF            2                2
VB             6                6
AAA            2                7
AAA            5                7
```

The algorithm should select the rows that sum up to the column c. The algorithm can select a single row as long as its total sums up to the number in column c but we only take the first occurance that sum up to column c and leave out the rest, then have a new data Frame

Comment: What if c is 6 for example and there are two rows that have 3 and 4?

Comment: then we show both rows and add another column with a minus figure, in this case i would add a difference column and the  -1 value will be added to the row that exceeds the required value. 

                     **A**        **B**             **c**      difference


                       XCD            3                6               0       
                       XCD           4                 6               -1
                       AA               1                4                 0    
                       AA               2                4                 2

Comment: I don't think this is doable in `pandas` context. [Subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is a difficult problem.

Comment: This is more less the same as getting the values in an array that sum up to a given value